Unable to access a Class within a PHP function
I'm trying to run MailerSend, an outbound email platform. I've loaded the necessary code onto my server and MailerSend works fine if I place the following code in a single PHP file and execute that file - let's call it 'SendAnEmail.php" :
    require '/home/xxxxx/vendor/autoload.php';
    use MailerSend\MailerSend;
    use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\Recipient;
    use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\EmailParams;
    use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\Attachment;
    
    $mailersend = new MailerSend(['api_key' => $apiKey]);
        $recipients[] = new Recipient($email, '');
    $emailParams = (new EmailParams())
        ->setFrom('fromemail.com')
        ->setFromName('My System')
        ->setRecipients($recipients)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setHtml('This is the HTML content')
        ->setText('This is the text content')
        ->setReplyTo('replyto@mysite.com')
        ->setReplyToName('My System')
        ->setAttachments($attachments);

    // send the email
        $response = $mailersend->email->send($emailParams);



The problem is that I want this code to be executed inside a function, so I can call the function from multiple php scripts within the system, send the function the basic info (to address, subject line, body text, etc) and have the function send the email. I can't get this to work - when I put the first five lines of the code above into the calling PHP script I get an error "Class 'Recipient' not found". If I put the first five lines of code above into the function I get a syntax error "unexpected 'use' " pointing to the first 'use' statement.
I am not an expert at PHP. I know how to expose regular variables from the calling script to the function using a global statement inside the function, but I don't know how to expose the Receipient class, or the other classes I need, inside the function.
I hope this question makes sese - I'm not exactly sure I'm using the correct terminology. Any help is appreciated.
Regards.

Please post your version of the function that you are trying to write, even if it isn't working

Apologies - the answer below solved the problem. The function which was being called, FYI, was using the MailerSend class to send the email - it was code that was working in a standalone file and - once the Class was "available" to the code inside the function - the function worked fine as well.

Would be something like this:
sendAnEmail.php
require '/home/xxxxx/vendor/autoload.php';
    use MailerSend\MailerSend;
    use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\Recipient;
    use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\EmailParams;
    use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\Attachment;
    
function sendEmail($email, $subject, $body) {

    $mailersend = new MailerSend(['api_key' => $apiKey]);
        $recipients[] = new Recipient($email, '');
    $emailParams = (new EmailParams())
        ->setFrom('fromemail.com')
        ->setFromName('My System')
        ->setRecipients($recipients)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setHtml('This is the HTML content')
        ->setText('This is the text content')
        ->setReplyTo('replyto@mysite.com')
        ->setReplyToName('My System')
        ->setAttachments($attachments);

    // send the email
        $response = $mailersend->email->send($emailParams);

  
}

and then in whatever file you want to call that function you put and it will inject all the code you have in your first file so you can use it as if it is pasted where the require is
File 2
require 'path/to/sendAnEmail.php';
$email = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'You won a FREE CAR!!!!';
$body = 'CONGRATS!';

sendEmail($email, $subject, $body)


